# Can We use Multiple AWS ACM Certificates at Nginx-Ingress-Contoller OR Multiple ACM certificate at Ingress object level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We are using EKS and Nginx-ingress(NLB). I'm trying to configure multiple AWS ACM certificates in the AWS-load-balancer-SSL-cert annotation for NLB. But with no luck. Could someone help if it possible at all? Thanks

If that not possible, Please guide me any other way on how to use multiple ACM cert in the ingress object-level if possible.

**My EXACT Scenario:-**

I am using an NLB (FYI)

If we able to add multiple ACM certificate at controller level that also works for me (I am using a single certificate  in my NLB currently see below annotations)

At the controller level, these flags help me to add a single certificate:-

```yaml
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:ap-south-1:1234556677:certificate/3a1d5a-469b-dffe4bad3182
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

or

I am maintaining an ingress object as per NameSpace. if we are able to attach a Certificate at the ingress object level, which also solves my problem.

Answer (score 7):

Good question.

There is no support for multiple ACM certificates on an ALB/NLB that points to an nginx ingress controller (or any other ingress controller AFAIK).

The dirty hack from Kubernetes is to create another `Service` that points to the same nginx ingress controller (same selectors) but in this case, it will just create another ALB/NLB and you may not want that.

The non-Kubernetes way which is the way might work better for you is just to do it from AWS itself and modify the ALB/NLB that sends traffic to your nginx ingress.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

✌️

Comment: means we can add multiple certificate at AWS level ?

Comment: I've tried this but it's not working! I have added 3 certificates to AWS's LoadBalancer yet in my kubernetes cluster still getting certificate error in my java application that says `PKIX path building failed unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: Is your Java app service https traffic itself?  maybe it needs a certificate at that level

Answer (score 3):

To add in Rico's answer.

It's not possible to attach multiple **certificates** to the Nginx ingress controller or any other ingress with `annotation : service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert`.

Closed **PR** : https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/95208

Issue thread: https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws/issues/80#issuecomment-686722657

It's not working with **NLB** However if you are using the **ALB** you can use this **annotation**

**Single** cert with **ALB**

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxxx:certificate/xxxxxxx
```

**Multiple certificates**

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxxx:certificate/cert1,arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxxx:certificate/cert2,arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxxx:certificate/cert3
```

`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn` specifies the ARN of one or more certificates managed by **ACM**

---

**Another Option For NLB**

Create an **ACM** certificate with multiple Wild card domains and use this single **Cert** with ingress. this will work with **NLB** also

So your **ACM** certificate will be storing **certs** for multiple domains example

```
*.example.com
*.hello.io
*.so.in
```

**single ACM** certificate now you can use with **NLB** **Ingress**, and no need worry about attaching multiple certs.

---

**Option : 2 using cert-manager and storing cert in secret**

It would be better if you planning to use multiple domains use **wild** **card** certificates with [Cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) store them into **Secret** of **K8s** and use it as **pluggable** solution with ingress.

Answer (score 1):

I think both the other answers are old and not valid now as I got confused reading those as they mention that its not possible to add 2 certs for NLB. However, you can easily add certs on nginx ingress controller with the annotation in a comma separated string. I myself have deployed AWS LB Controller and using nginx ingress controller to deploy `NLB`. My annotations on nginx ingress controller service

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:123456:certificate/123abc,arn:aws:acm:eu-central-1:123456:certificate/123xyz
```

and I have 2 ACM certs attached to my load balancer both with separate URLs

- abc.com
- xyz.com

Please note you need to add `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external` as then it will use the AWS Load Balancer Controller

Comment: I've tried this but still it's not working

Comment: you might be doing something wrong..
as I have tried and its working in our prod at the moment

Comment: Your answer is not useful that's why I downvote it.

Comment: and that is what I am saying that it is working for me, the other answers are not valid now..
you can see https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/service/annotations/#tls

Comment: Check the line

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert` specifies the ARN of one or more certificates managed by the AWS Certificate Manager.

The first certificate in the list is the default certificate and remaining certificates are for the optional certificate list

Comment: Also I had confirmed from the nginx ingress slack chat in Kubernetes workspace, and the maintainer also confirmed it can be done...

Comment: Even one other user confirmed on official slack chat that he was able to do it using the way I mentioned
https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/CANQGM8BA/p1678805810014759?thread_ts=1676465593.403039&cid=CANQGM8BA

Comment: Thanks Ali for the clarification.